# How can i cast a float variable (0.0) in a string class

Tags: ruby, string, class, casting

i have a value returned in json of float type like 0.0 of Float Class

this look good, but when I try to convert to string it change to "0.0"

The Console shows this :

```
irb(main):080:0> commission.class
=> Float
irb(main):081:0> commission.to_s
=> "0.0"
irb(main):082:0> commission.class
=> Float
irb(main):083:0> commission.class
=> Float
```

Can anyone help me to understand this behavior. Why class are still float?

Comment: `commission.to_s` _returns_ a string. If you want to change the variable you have to assign the return value to it, i.e.  `commission = commission.to_s`.

Comment: very simple no?, yeah i change the output with the _s...
thanks for the explanation :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, the Class of an Object does not change. Ever. Some methods can result in a *new* object from another class. The original object does not transform or cease to exist.

Comment: "Some methods can result in a new object". That is the behavior of all the `to_x` methods in Ruby. They return a new object in the desired class but never mutate the recipient. Or at least thats how they should behave...

Comment: great to know knoledgment, my approach now is, change by the & operator &comission